How to mock window.location in jasmine and preact unit testing
How to mock window.location in jasmine unit testing?
onDeleteConfirm is main function:(After adding the window.location the test case was not working.)
Here how to mock or spy the window.location in unit test?
function onDeleteConfirm() {
    setSuccessMessage(null);

    const sectionIds = getSelectedSectionIds().toString();
    sectionsService.deleteSections(sectionIds).then(function (result) {
        window.location = `/testing1/api/gap/export/files?fileIdentifier=${result}&storeFile=true`;
        setSections(sections.filter((s) => !s.selected));
        setSuccessMessage('Sections have been deleted successfully.');
    });
}

Existing Unit tests:
describe('onDeleteConfirm', function () {
    let wrapper, confirmDeleteModal;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
        jasmineEnzyme();

        mockDataForSuccessRender();

        wrapper = Enzyme.mount(html`<${Index} />`);
        await testUtils.resolveImmediately();
        wrapper.update();

        const index = sections.findIndex((x) => x.sectionId === 174610);
        const sectionToUpdate = sections[index];
        sectionToUpdate.selected = true;
        sections.splice(index, 1, sectionToUpdate);
        wrapper.update();
        
        confirmDeleteModal = wrapper.find('ConfirmModal[id="confirmDeleteModal"]');
    });

    it('should call deleteSections onDeleteConfirm', async function () {
        // Act
        await preactTestUtils.act(function () {
            confirmDeleteModal.prop('onConfirm')();
        });

        await testUtils.resolveImmediately();
        wrapper.update();

        // Assert
        expect(sectionsService.deleteSections).toHaveBeenCalledWith('174610');
    });
});

